# how to give action to UIButtoun Outlet from another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, iboutlet

I have two `UIViewController` class with names : (`RootViewController` & `SecondViewController`).
I have one `UIButton` Outlet in my `SecondViewController`.now I want give action method to my `UIButton` in `RootViewController`.but I don't know about it.

please guide me and tell me how to get my `UIButton` in another View and give action method on it in another View....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing this, it doesn't look good.
Anyway, here's the way.

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewcontroller:UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
SecondViewContoller * sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[sv.theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You have to removeTarget when you've done with the button.

Why don't you use delegate or block callback?

**ADDED**

***delegate***

SecondViewController.h

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)theButtonPressed;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@interface SecondViewController ()
{
    UIButton *theButton;
}
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [theButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(theButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
@end
```

RootViewcontroller.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
SecondViewController *sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[sv setDelegate:self];
```

and

```
- (void)theButtonPressed
{
}
```

***block***

SecondViewController.h

```
typedef void(^TheButtonTouched)(void);

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
- (void)addButtonEvent:(TheButtonTouched)event;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@interface SecondViewController ()
{
    UIButton *theButton;
    TheButtonTouched buttonBlock;
}
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // button alloc init here and..
    [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(buttonBlock)
    {
        buttonBlock();
    }
}

- (void)addButtonEvent:(TheButtonTouched)event
{
    buttonBlock = event;
}
@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
SecondViewController *sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[sv addButtonEvent:^{
    // ADD SOMTHING HERE
}];
```

Comment: my friend thanks for guidence. I have one question. theButtonPressed action where is it???

Comment: I missed that.. just added.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create RootViewController 's Object and passed into target parameter.

e.g.

```
[btnShow addTarget:self.rootCtrlObj action:@selector(viewPhoto_click:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

where rootCtrlObj is @property inside `SecondViewController.h` file
and when you push this controller in RootViewController you have to pass reference of RootViewController .

```
For Example,

secVCObj.rootCtrlObj = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secVCObj animated:YES];
```

Comment: my friend what is btnShow?

Comment: btnShow is just button inside your SecondViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to  create the button's iboutlet property.
Than  using object of secondclass.button name you can assign selector.

```
[classobjectname..btnname addTarget:objectname.class action:@selector(objectname.methodname:);
```

Comment: my friend I so confused!!! classobjectname??? objectname??? what is it??? please guide me with my classes (RootViewController & SecondViewController).

Comment: ok. create object of SecondViewController in RootViewController than using it   [SecondViewControllerObject.btnname addTarget:SecondViewControllerObjecte.class action:@selector(SecondViewControllerobjectname.methodname:);

Answer (score 0):

as i said custom delegate methods will work perfect for these cases,
in `SecondViewController.h` file define a custom delegate method like below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@protocol SecondControllerDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)someActionToPerformInRootController; 
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondControllerDelegate>delegate; //declare a custom delegate
@end
```

in `SecondViewController.m` file lets take an action of some button

```
- (IBAction)myButtonActionMethod:(id)sender
{
  if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someActionToPerformInRootController)])
   {
      [self.delegate someActionToPerformInRootController]; //this will call the delegate method in first view conroller( root view controller) //do what ever u want t do in the action method of rootviewcontroller
  }
}
```

in `RootViewController.h` file

```
 #import "SecondViewController.h"
 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController  < SecondControllerDelegate> //confirmas to delegate
```

in `RootViewController.m` while presenting the `SecondViewController` set the delegate to `self`

```
- (IBAction)showAction:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondController.delegate = self; //call back to this controller
    [self presentViewController:secondController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//this method called from the secondViewcontroller
- (void) someActionToPerformInRootController
{
    NSLog(@"perform action in root view controller");
}
```

Comment: my friend in your code where is it my button action?

Comment: hmm well `showAction` is the action method to show secondviewcontroller and in the secondviewcontroller `someActionPerform` is the action method in secondviewcontroller where u want to call the action method of rootviewcontroller instead of that i am calling the `actionToPerform` method of rootviewcontroller